# How do I prevent late replies to a TCP socket?

Tags: c, sockets, connection-pooling

I'm writing a database library that will have to intelligently support timeouts. Now that I'm looking at connection pooling, I'm particularly worried about the following scenario:

1. Send Query #1
2. Time out after *n* seconds.
3. Send Query #2
4. Receive a response to query #1

Step four can happen, because the queries are not marked with a query ID: all I know is I've received a response, and I don't know which query it belongs to. One could argue that this constitutes a mistake in the protocol, but that's not up to me.

Before sending query #2, what should I do to the socket to avoid such a late reply? Is the only correct way to `shutdown()`, `close()` and re-`connect()`?

Comment: What about adding constant to the select of all queries so your library could identify which query the response is for?

Comment: That is a great idea, but sadly not very good for a library. Maybe via a plugin...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid this is the only safe way to operate your connection, because there is no other way to get a one-to-one between question and answer over TCP. There seems to be a lack of some sort of a **cancel** function inbetween.

This reference gives more insight: http://www.ssfnet.org/Exchange/tcp/tcpTutorialNotes.html

Comment: In turn, that's because TCP knows nothing of your so-called "queries", "responses", or "cancels". A connected socket is just two unidirectional tubes for bytes (Ted Stevens was right). If one ends writes stuff in and the creek don't rise, then the other end can read it. So establishing what "query" that "response" is "for" is an application-level problem. Either it's built into the protocol that defines the query/response, or it doesn't exist.

Comment: I mean, I know. :-) But TCP does have sequence numbers, so I was hoping there was some sort of trick I could leverage.

Comment: @Andres: unfortunately sequence numbers just let the TCP layer assemble the stream - there's nothing to say how much time elapsed between particular bytes in opposite directions. Remember that just because `n` seconds elapsed since you send the first request, doesn't mean `n` seconds elapsed since the other end read it. So the other end might have sent that response *before* the timeout from its POV, but it arrived with you after the timeout from your POV. Timeouts alone could work with a reliable, time-synchronized connection, which TCP is not.